# Jquery exclude type with multiple selectors

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui

I have a mvc view page which is resulting in multiple elements with same name. 
I want to exclude all the input elements whose type is hidden while validating the form.

For example my page results with below inputs :

```
<input name="[0].MPID" type="hidden" value="">
<input name="[1].MPID" type="hidden" value="">
....

<input id="MPID_0" name="[0].MPID" type="text" value="" class="valid">
<input id="MPID_1" name="[1].MPID" type="text" value="" class="valid">
....
```

Now when I am writing below code to loop all MPID elements I dont want to consider first set of input which are of type hidden.

```
      $("[name$='\\.MPID']").each(function () {
            // this here refers to the found element
            var $this = $(this);
...
....
        })
```

To accommodate that I changed the selector as below, I am getting error in console. Kindly help me by rectifying the second exclude selector properly.

```
$("[name$='\\.MPID' input:not(type=hidden)]").each(function () {
....
})
```

Comment: It just needs to be $`('input[type="text"]).each(...` but you do realize that you will never get any client side validation and that if you submit a form that it will only ever bind to the values in the hidden inputs?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've seen, your selector isn't quite right. Try this:

```
$('input:visible[name$="\\.MPID"]').each(function () {
    // ....
})
```

Note that the element type selector comes first and is outside the attribute selector. Also, you can use `:visible` instead of `:not(:hidden)`, or `:not([type="hidden"])`.